# Magento 2.2.4 : How to change Footer Copyright in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2.4

I tried changing footer copyright in **Content->Configuration** Edit Active Theme and Change Copyright Message in Footer Tab.
But I get Error as "**Area is Already Set**" on Saving it.

So, How to Change Footer Copyright Message in Magento 2?

Comment: please can check my answer and let me know if any issues generate.

Comment: Did you add extra rather than my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as explained by Sukumar Gorai it is a bug with Magento 2.2.4. Personally I have upgraded to 2.2.6 and it solved the issue. I used the following commands:

```
sudo composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.2 --no-update
sudo composer update
sudo rm -rf var/cache var/di var/generation var/page_cache
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

followed by a running of a personal script that re-deploys all static content and fixes permissions.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The issue is in Magento 2.2.4 and its resolved in upper version. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug in Magento 2.2.4: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14968

You can resolve this by following:

Change in **vendor\magento\module-email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php** this:

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if($this->area) {
        throw new \LogicException(__('Area is already set'));
    }
    $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    return $this;
}
```

With this:

```
public function setForcedArea($templateId)
{
    if(!isset($this->area)) {
        $this->area = $this->emailConfig->getTemplateArea($templateId);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing from specific theme

Go to **Content > Design > Configuration > Global**

Edit it Under Footer tab update copyright text and save it.